# Java: looping over clases

Tags: java

Say I have a java method like:

```
  public boolean isTestRenewalRequired(int versionId, ReleaseVersion releaseVersion, Class<?> entityCls, int results) {
    Class<?>[] clases = {Test1.class, Test2.class, Test3.class, Test4.class};
    boolean hasResults = false;
    final CommonCriteriaQueryBuilder qBuilder = CommonCriteriaQueryBuilder.getInstance(crudService, entityCls);
    for (Class<?> c: clases) {
    if (ReleaseVersionStatusEnum.F.equals(releaseVersion.getStatus())) {
      c.equals(qBuilder);
      qBuilder.whereEqual("tempReleaseVersion", releaseVersion.getId().toString());      
    } else if (ReleaseVersionStatusEnum.W.equals(releaseVersion.getStatus())) {
      c.equals(qBuilder);
      qBuilder.whereEqual("releaseVersion", releaseVersion.getId().toString());
    }
      
      if (results > 0) {
        hasResults = true;
      }
    }
    
    return hasResults;
  }
```

The commoncriteriaquerybuilder allows me to compare two java classes tempReleaseVersion and ReleaseVersion. My question is how can I loop the java clases (Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4) over the if conditions?
For c.equals(qBuilder) I got the following warning: Unlikely argument type for equals(): CommonCriteriaQueryBuilder seems to be unrelated to Class<capture#6-of ?> and Remove this call to "equals"; comparisons between unrelated types always return false.

```
public enum ReleaseVersionStatusEnum {
  W, // Wait for release / in work
  F, // Released for approval
  L, // Deleted / Rejected
}
```

Could anybody help me and give me a hint?

Comment: You cannot compare an object when only the content of components are different. You have to use Reflection to extract the relevant fields and compare them to the values you want to know.

Comment: Ok how can I do this?

Comment: Well, It requires you some experiences with Reflection: Field[] fd = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields() then loop each field for the content...